# Unable to install ubuntu desktop guest using KVM

Tags: 10.10, installation, kvm-virtualization

I'm unable to install ubuntu 10.10amd64 (or i386) onto a ubuntu amd64 server running KVM. However I'm able to install Ubuntu server fine into the same KVM.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm trying to manage the install using virt-manager so it connects to the host server using ssh tunneling.

The cd seems to boot up ok but it hangs once I click Install Ubuntu and the mouse cursor only sometimes responds. When trying to install i386 I eventually get the following error:

Installation failed

The Installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again.

Once I press ok I get a LiveCD environment it's not really usable and the gnome-panel keeps disappearing. It looks like the window decorations are missing (maybe it's a graphics problem?). Then the panel completely disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Ubuntu 10.10 desktop installer requires at least 512MB memory (according to some forum posts, I was unable to find an official system requirements page) and the 256MB I was giving the VM just wasn't cutting it.